# Triangular mesh in PGFPlots instead of rectangular

Tags: pgfplots

Recently I had to reinstall my OS, and with it the LaTeX system also. Now if I compile the same code as before, on surface plots PGFPlots generates triangular mesh instead of the wanted and usual rectangular. I have looked for a solution in the manual, but it seems that rectangular should be the default one.

The code is:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}        
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        width=0.6\textwidth,
        grid=major,
        colormap={jet}{rgb255(0cm)=(0,0,255)
            rgb255(1cm)=(0,255,255) rgb255(2cm)=(255,255,0) rgb255(3cm)=(255,0,0)
            },
        shader=faceted interp,
        colorbar,
        view={70}{40}
        ]
        \addplot3[surf,faceted color=white, opacity=0.9,patch type=rectangle,] table [row sep=newline] {_plotdata/tors/perfor.dat};
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

While perfor.dat contains:

```
1   27  144
1   29  131
1   31  120
1   33  110
1   35  110
1   37  88
1   39  86
1   41  82
1   43  75
1   45  70

3   27  90
3   29  82
3   31  77
3   33  70
3   35  65
3   37  60
3   39  55
3   41  52
3   43  48
3   45  46
```

And it results in the following image:
[image: resulted plot]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is a bug which was present in `pgfplots 1.5`. It has been fixed since `pgfplots 1.6`. The current stable is `pgfplots 1.10`.

Upgrading `pgfplots` will repair the regression; please use the update mechanisms of your TeX distribution.

Comment: thank you! the coorporate version was a bit old, although contained miktex 2.9